# How can I read / write using YAML?

Tags: ruby

I have been trying to write a program that handles space delimited arguments via STDIN.

```
echo "Add Tom 4111111111111111 $1000" | ruby basicCC.rb
echo "Charge Tom $500" | ruby basicCC.rb
echo "Charge Tom $800" | ruby basicCC.rb
```

This is my code:

```
load 'creditCard.rb'
require 'yaml'
people = YAML::load_file "settings.yml"
puts people.inspect
data = ARGF.read
puts people

def run(file, people)
  rand_num = Random.rand(9999)
  file.each_line do |line, index|
    line = line.split(' ')
    function = line[0]
    if function == 'Add'
      name, cc, limit = line[1..-1]
      limit = limit[1..-1].to_i
      people[name] = Credit.new(name, cc, limit)
    elsif function == 'Charge'
      name, amount = line[1..-1]
      amount = amount[1..-1].to_i
      if people[name].nil?
        puts "Could not find #{name}"
      else
        people[name].charge(amount)
      end
    elsif function == 'Credit'
      name, amount = line[1..-1]
      amount = amount[1..-1].to_i
      if people[name].nil?
        puts "Could not find #{name}"
      else
        people[name].credit(amount)
      end
    end
    puts people
    File.open("settings.yml", "w") do |file|
      file.write people[name].to_yaml
    end
  end
end

run(data, people)
```

I cannot figure out how to write and read my settings.yml. I cannot execute `"Charge Tom $500"` because there is no data to read from and edit.

Comment: are you trying to `yml` as your repository? this is not a very good use case... if you want a light-weight file-based repository, you should consider sqlite. YML mainly used for text-based configuration files (they are read-only...)

Comment: [here](http://zetcode.com/db/sqliteruby/) is a sqlite+ruby tutorial

Comment: As mentioned, you certainly should be using Sqlite for this requirement. But I would like to note a few aspects:

1. `echo "$with_dollar_sign_in_front"` will be interpolated as a environment variable if provided in double quotes. So, either escape it or use single quotes.

2. Perhaps try parsing with `STDIN.readlines`.

3. Also do check if your yaml file is proper.

Comment: Don't talk directly to SQLite. That ties your code to closely to the DBM and makes porting to another DBM more work. Instead, look at using an ORM, which abstracts away the pain and makes it very easy to develop, test, and run in production, and, in the future, easily move to something like PostgreSQL, MySQL or Oracle. I recommend using [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net).

Comment: @nanSTA, you attempted to delete the code in my answer by editing it. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you're trying to read space delimited arguments from the command-line, then later say the problem is that you can't read the YAML file. When you ask a question, it's important to remain clear about what you want to accomplish with the question. Failure to do that results in down-votes and questions getting closed.

Your code isn't very well structured. I'd write it like this (untested) code:

```
require 'yaml'
require_relative 'creditCard.rb'

def process_data(new_data, data_store)

  new_data.each_line do |line, index|

    line = line.split
    function = line.shift

    case function
    when 'Add'

      name, cc, limit = line
      limit = limit[1..-1].to_i
      data_store[name] = Credit.new(name, cc, limit)

    when 'Charge'
      name, amount = line
      amount = amount[1..-1].to_i

      if data_store[name]
        data_store[name].charge(amount)
      else
        puts "Could not find #{name}"
      end

    when 'Credit'

      name, amount = line
      amount = amount[1..-1].to_i

      if data_store[name]
        data_store[name].credit(amount)
      else
        puts "Could not find #{name}"
      end

    end

    puts data_store

    File.write("settings.yml", data_store.to_yaml)

  end
end

people = YAML::load_file "settings.yml"
process_data(ARGF.read, people)
```

Things that stood out in your code:

- The formatting (spacing and indentation) wasn't good. Code needs to have whitespace in it, which allows our eyes and brain to more easily see the logic. White space doesn't slow down a program's execution speed, and it makes a big difference when maintaining the code, so put it in.
- Use `require_relative` if you're reading in code from a separate file that is in the same directory. (Also, don't use camelCase to name files, use snake_case. It's anotherOfThoseReadabilityThings.)
- Don't call a method `run`. Use a name that indicates what it is doing or is going to return. In this case `run` means nothing, but `process_data` does.
- The parameter names used for the passed in data don't reflect what the data is, but those, plus the name of the method should give you a good clue what the routine does.

  ```
  process_data(new_data, data_store)
  ```

  tells us more than

  ```
  run(file, people)
  ```
- `split(' ')` does the same as `split` so use the shorter form.
- `function = line[0]` forces you to repeatedly access `line[1..-1`. Instead use `line.shift`, which cleans up the other accesses to `line`.
- `if`/`elseif`/`else` chains are noisy. `case`/`when` cleans it up nicely.

You weren't writing the complete YAML file back to disk, instead you were overwriting the file with a single name's information. I don't think that's what you intended, so

```
File.write("settings.yml", data_store.to_yaml)
```

will rewrite the whole file, which should fix the problem.